# Two Versions of JPA entities for a Single Table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Hi How do I get Two JPA entities for a Single Table.

I'm trying to achieve One Lighter Version with out any Joins (For List Page).
and One Heavier version with all mappings (For View Details Page).

For Example the Entity can be 'User' where the List page will only display records from User Table and upon Clicking on User Name will display other User details where It fetches records from other mapped entities like Preferences etc.

Comment: maybe better to create a view and map it to that

Comment: Why would you need two entities to do that? You know that associations can be lazy-loaded, right?

Comment: I was thinking two entities are required to do that .. But would like to know the other possibilities for this.

Comment: If you are looking for a lighter version you can look into projections.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the entity below:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private int age;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Email> emailSet;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Person> childrenSet;

    // get and set
}
```

In the entity above it is possible to see an entity with two collections. If you run the JPQL below, those entities will not be loaded.

```
select p from Person p where p.id = 33
// or 
select p from Person p where p.name = 'uaiHebert'
```

Why? All entities with any kind of '*Many*' annotation (@OneToMany or @ManyToMany) will be lazy loaded.

What is lazy loaded? Lazy Loaded means that that attribute will not loaded from the database until you use it. In the entity above, the email would be loaded only when `person.getEmailSet()` were invoked.

You do not need other entity to make a faster database loading, you need to use JPA without EAGER relationships.

If you set the `emailSet` like below, every time that you load a Person its `emailSet` will be loaded too.

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Email> emailSet;
```

Be careful for the error LazyInitializationException that is, if you invoke `person.getEmailSet()` with the transaction closed. For more info about this exception check this link: http://uaihebert.com/four-solutions-to-the-lazyinitializationexception/